# Как изменить версию python между минорными релизами?

Tags: python

Есть проект, который требует конкретную версию питона - 3.8.0(это обязательное требование). На машине стоит версия 3.8.10. Могу ли я как то свитчнуться между этими минорными версиями? (ОС - Ubuntu)

Comment: Можете. Что именно вас интересует?